# eof problem c++

Tags: c++, fstream, eof, dev-c++

i am using Dev C++ on windows xp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string STRING;
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open ("sample.txt");
        while(!infile.eof)
        {
            getline(infile,STRING); 
            cout<<STRING; 
        }
    infile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

this codes gives the following error

```
C:\C++\read.cpp: In function `int main()':

C:\C++\read.cpp:11: error: could not convert `infile.std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>::eof [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]' to `bool'
C:\C++\read.cpp:11: error: in argument to unary !
```

i am not sure what is wrong here i cant compile the code 
please help

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but Dev-C++ is really outdated. Try using [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26) with MingW or [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-CPP) instead

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @ Firas Assaad , i have used visual studio express , but its slows down my poor pc, i will try code::blocks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you change your loop to

```
  while(getline(infile,STRING))
  {
     cout<<STRING; 
  }
```

you avoid the possibility of reading the last value twice (see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647/c-reading-from-text-file-until-eof-repeats-last-line)).

Comment: what if i use get() to read single char like infile.get() , then how do i control the loop without using infile.eof() ?

Comment: @user721776: So long as you assign the result to an `int` (`std::istream::int_type`) and not a `char` (`std::istream::char_type`) then on all reasonable platforms you can reliably test against `EOF` (`std::istream::traits_type::eof()`) as your loop condition.

Comment: @user721776 infile.get() with no arguments returns an int that you can test against *the value* EOF. In contrast, `infile.get(c)` where c is a character returns an istream object that you can check to see if it's null in the while loop condition just like with getline.

Answer (score 10):

`std::ifstream::eof` is a function that returns a bool. Thsu you have to call it like

```
infile.eof()
```

Comment: Please don't suggest using `.eof()` as a loop condition. It is almost always incorrect.

Answer (score 8):

You forgot the `()` after the `eof`.