# Removing a space from lines in the beginning of a text file

Tags: c++

I have a C++ snippet that removes the first word of a line in a text file e.g.

```
test C:\Windows\System32
download C:\Program Files\test.exe
```

Although it removes the first word, there is a space left over after trimming it, is there a way to stop remove this space?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string tmp;
   while ( !cin.eof() )
   {
      cin >> tmp;
      getline(cin, tmp);
      cout << tmp << endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: This isn't C, this is C++. There is a difference. If I see another question confusing the two I'm going to go regex-Cthulhu crazy.

Comment: also, this isn't widows, it's windows!

Comment: possible duplicate of [eof problem c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764579/eof-problem-c)

Comment: This is hardly Windows-specific, unnecessary tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to trim `tmp` before streaming it to `cout`. Use your favourite `trim` function from a library, or write your own.

You can find some options for trim functions here: [What's the best way to trim std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216823/whats-the-best-way-to-trim-stdstring)

Once you have a trim function, and Evan Teran's versions look rather fine, you then can write:

```
   cin >> tmp;
   getline(cin, tmp);
   cout << trim(tmp) << endl;
```