# How to read from a file into a doubly linked list?

Tags: c++, file, doubly-linked-list

This is a small part of my project at school. I have stored my data into a text file in this form:

```
bike
dock
car
```

Now, I would like to read the data from this file into a doubly linked list. This is the code I used.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <strings.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class item
{
public:
    string name;
    item *next;
    item *previous;
};

class list:private item
{
    item * first;
public:
    list();
    void load();
    void display();
};

list::list()
{
    first = NULL;
}

void list::load()
{
    item *current;
    ifstream fin;

    fin.open("List.txt");

    current=new item;

    while(!fin.eof())
    {
        fin>>current->name;
        current->previous=NULL;
        current->next=NULL;
    }

    fin.close();

    first=current;
}
```

Now, the problem is I am unable to store each word of the file into a new node. This code stores the last word of the file to the first node of the list. I have no clue how to do this. I am not that good in linked lists. Can anyone help me resolve this problem?

Comment: You allocate only one single item with `new` outside the loop. You should allocate a new item for each word read from the file.

Comment: Any reason you aren't using `std::list`?

Comment: You are trying to do too much at once. You should try constructing a list from hard-coded data, before you worry about file I/O.

Comment: You do the `new item` outside of the loop, so you only get one node in the  list. Also, using `while(!fin.eof)` is [almost always the wrong way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764579/eof-problem-c).

Comment: @Beta he probably wants to practice.

Comment: I am still learning C++. Our teacher just started teaching us linked lists. We were not taught anything about std::list . That's the reason I am not using it.

Comment: @VipanchithReddy In that case you might want to make it clear in the question that this is homework, otherwise you'll just get a 4-line solution using the library.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention that. I have now added it to the question.

Comment: @Michael Walz I know I am creating only a single node. That's the problem. I have no clue how to store each word in a separate node.

Comment: @VipanchithReddy you need one node for each word. Take a pice of paper and a pencil and draw your linked list. I think you are missing the very basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,  try something like this for the load function (not tested):

```
void list::load()
{
    item *current;
    item *prev;
    ifstream fin;

    fin.open("List.txt");


    prev = NULL;
    while(!fin.eof())
    {
        current=new item;
        if (first == NULL) // we set first the first time
            first = current;
        fin>>current->name;
        current->previous=prev;
        current->next = NULL;
        if (prev != NULL)
            prev->next=current;
        prev = current; // we store the current as the prev for next iteration
    }

    fin.close();
}
```

Comment: the (prev != NULL) should be setting prev->next, whereas current->previous will always = prev (even if its NULL)

Comment: It worked after doing that change. The problem was I was actually testing the sample code in a new project which didn't have the text file in it. So, it had no file to load. Thank you for your help.