# Ofstream adds extra characters to my output

Tags: c++, encryption, ifstream, ofstream

I'm making a enciphering/deciphering program using XTEA algorithm. The encipher/decipher functions work fine, but when I encipher a file and then decipher it, I get some extra characters in the end of the file:

```
--- Original file ---
QwertY

--- Encrypted file ---
»¦æŸS@±­

--- Deciphered from encrypted ---
QwertY  ß*tÞÇ
```

I have no idea why the "  ß*tÞÇ" appears in the end. 
I will post some of my code, but not all of it since it would be too long. The encipher/decipher function takes 64 bits data and 128 bits key, and encipher/decipher the data to the same block size, which is again 64 bits ([similar functions here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XTEA)). It can then be written to a new file.

```
    long data[2]; // 64bits
    ZeroMemory(data, sizeof(long)*2);
    char password[16];
    ZeroMemory(password, sizeof(char)*16);

    long *key;
    if(argc > 1)
    {
        string originalpath = argv[1];
        string finalpath;
        string eextension = "XTEA";
        string extension = GetFileExtension(originalpath);
        bool encipherfile = 1;

        if(extension.compare(eextension) == 0) // If extensions are equal, dont encipher file
        {
            encipherfile = 0;
            finalpath = originalpath;
            finalpath.erase(finalpath.length()-5, finalpath.length());
        }

        ifstream in(originalpath, ios::binary);
        ofstream out(finalpath, ios::binary);

        cout << "Password:" << endl;
        cin.get(password,sizeof(password));
        key = reinterpret_cast<long *>(password);

        while(!in.eof())
        {
            ZeroMemory(data, sizeof(long)*2);
            in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data), sizeof(long)*2); // Read 64bits from file

            if(encipherfile == 1)
            {
                encipher(data, key);
                out.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data), sizeof(data));
                continue;
            }
            if(encipherfile == 0)
            {
                decipher(data, key);
                out.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data), sizeof(data));
            }
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading from text file until EOF repeats last line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647/reading-from-text-file-until-eof-repeats-last-line)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I can assure you this is not a duplicate... You see in the link you gave me, they read 1 char at a time. I read a 64 bit block at a time, and even though the block only receives 1 byte before EOF, I should still be able to encipher/decipher it, and then the loop won't run again.

Comment: The block actually receives zero bytes before EOF. You still decipher and write one more time. The point is that `in.eof()` tells us if the previous read failed, not if the next read will be successful.

Comment: This is a common problem. [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5605159/445976)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for `eof` immediately after your read, and if you get `eof` break out of the loop.

If you may have partial reads (i.e. it is possible to read fewer than all of the requested bytes), then you need also to call `gcount` to find out how many bytes you actually read, thus:

```
cin.read( ... )
if( cin.eof() )
    {
    streamsize bytesRead = cin.gcount();
    if( bytesRead > 0 )
       // process those bytes
    break;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, it doesn't help. When I read a block of file, I might only read half of the buffer (4 bytes), and then hit the eof, and if I break out of the loop then, the 4 bytes would just get discarded, and not get encrypted neither written to the new file.

Comment: Modified answer to account for possibility of incomplete buffer.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the answer... There is just one more thing I have some problems with. Why does this happen only when I decipher? I mean, I use almost the same process for enciphering-deciphering.

Comment: Perhaps because you can readily see when its got longer than expected on decoding.  I can't really say without knowing more about the enciphering/deciphering process.