# What's wrong with this code?

Tags: c++

When I write `cout<< Read("filepath")`I get strange set of identical characters.  Code is below:

```
char* Read(std::string FilePath)
{
    char* Buffer;

    ifstream F_S(FilePath);
    while (! F_S.eof())

    {

        F_S.getline(Buffer,100);
        return Buffer; 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Multiple problems here:

Firstly, your `return` statement is inside your `while` loop, which means the loop will only execute once and then you'll just return from the function.  The `return` statement needs to be placed *outside* of the `while` loop.

Secondly, you don't allocate any storage for `Buffer`.  All you do is declare a `char*` pointer, which isn't even initialized.  You need to explicitly allocate storage so that `ifstream::getline` has somewhere to store the input.  You can use `new` to allocate storage, but since your `Read` function returns a `char*` pointer, the calling function would need to manually manage the memory, which is generally just a headache.

A better solution is to use the free function `std::getline`, since it takes an `std::string`, so you don't have to worry about storage allocation.  You'll also need to change the function signature of `Read` to return an `std::string`.

```
std::string Read(std::string FilePath)
{
    std::ifstream F_S(FilePath.c_str());
    /* You should also check for `F_S.good()` here */

    std::string result, Buffer; 
    while(std::getline(F_S, Buffer)) 
    {
        result += Buffer;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Note that if you want to preserve carriage returns in the file, you'll need to manually add them to `result` within each iteration, since `std::getline` discards delimiter characters.

Comment: Third problem. [*Never* use `.eof()` as a loop condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647/reading-from-text-file-until-eof-repeats-last-line). Also, your proposed solution only ever returns the last line read. Try: `std::string result, Buffer; while(std::getline(F_S, Buffer)) result += Buffer; return result;`

Comment: Another problem: `std::ifstream::open` requires a `char *`, not an `std::string`.  Use `std::string::c_str()`.

Comment: @Thomas, good catch: I didn't notice that because apparently, GCC accepts `std::ifstream::open(std::string)`.  I guess it's an extension.

Answer (score 0):

you can define your read  like this.

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string& Read(string file_path)
{
    ifstream infile(file_path.c_str(), ios::in);
    string result = "";
    string line = ""; 
    while (getline(infile, line)) 
    {
        result.append(line); //also you can use result+=line, but append is faster than +=
    }

    return result;

}
```

Comment: As [an anonymous user noted](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/247435), returning a reference here is probably wrong: it'll be a reference to a temporary string on the stack which will no longer exist outside the function. You should return just a `std::string` instead.

Comment: Also: why would the `result.append()` be quicker than `result += line`? I'd expect the implementation to be exactly the same!