# reading a file and splitting the line into individual variables

Tags: c++, getline

PROGRAM

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  string line,p1,p2,p3;
  ifstream myfile ("infile.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( myfile.good() )
    {
/*
      myfile >> p1 >> p2 >> p3 ;
      cout << "p1 : "  << p1 << "   p2 :  " << p2 << "   p3 :  "  << p3 << endl;
*/

      getline (myfile,line);
      cout << "line : " << line << endl;

    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file";

  return 0;
}
```

INFILE.TXT

```
name
param1 = xyz
param2 = 99
param3
param_abc = 0.1
june 2012
```

OUTPUT

```
line : name
line : param1 = xyz
line : param2 = 99
line : param3
line : param_abc = 0.1
line : june 2012
line :
```

i want to search for param2 and print its value i.e. 99

Comment: Have you looked up `std::map` and/or `std::multimap`?

Comment: [Please don't use `.good()` as a loop condition.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647/reading-from-text-file-until-eof-repeats-last-line) It often produces buggy code (as it did here). In your case, use the return value of `getline`: `while (std::getline(myfile,line)) { std::cout << "line : " << line << "\n"; }`

Answer (score 1):

after you read the line, you could parse it:

```
stringstream ss(line);
string token;
if (ss >> token && token == "param2") {
    ss >> token; // '='
    ss >> token; // value of param2
    cout << "param2 is: " << token << endl;
  }
}
```

You should add some more testing for the success of the read operations (and maybe that the token after "param2" is indeed `=`)

If the value of "param2" is expected to be an integer, you could extract that instead of the last token extraction:

```
int val;
ss >> val;
```

Comment: Thanks is there anyway to have a search array i.e. param1|param3|June

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "search array", but you could take a loot at `std::map<>`, although you can only have one type for the values (e.g. `string`)

Comment: i now have the following but it fails on

Comment: sub == param2#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  string line,p1,p2,p3;
  ifstream myfile ("infile.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( myfile.good() )
    {

      getline (myfile,line);
      /* cout << "line : " << line << endl; */
      istringstream iss(line) ;

      do
      {

      string sub ;
      iss >> sub ;
      cout << sub << endl ;
         if (sub == 'param2')
         {
           cout << "MATCH  : " << line << endl;
         }
      } while (iss) ;
-----

Comment: @user1234392 - did you mean `if (sub == "param2")` (note the quote `"` instead of `'` around _param2_)