# Reading a file of two columns into one array

Tags: c++

I have a very basic question. I'm trying to read from a file that has data saved like this:

```
Collins, Bill
Smith, Bart
Allen, Jim
.
.
.
Holland, Beth
```

and I would like my code to read the data and save them into one column of an array. So what I did was,

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstring>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string first, last, FIRST[200], LAST[200];

ifstream infile;
infile.open("names.dat");

while (!infile.eof())
{
for (int i = 0; i < !infile.eof(); i++)
{
    infile >> first;
    FIRST[i] = first;
    cout << FIRST[i] << " ";

    infile >> last;
    LAST[i] = last;
    cout << LAST[i] << " " << endl;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

However, I want just one array named NAME[], not two(FIRST[] & LAST[]). So basically if I call NAME[0] would be Collins, Bill.

I really don't know how to do this... reading sources makes me even more confused..

This is just a little part of the entire program that I have to write, which is sorting names alphabetically and I haven't even passed this stage yet.

Comment: So, why don't you use one 2D array then with proper indexing?

Comment: Why: `i < !infile.eof()` !?

Comment: @LaszloPapp so like NAMES[][] ??

Comment: @DieterLücking cuz I thought I needed to do i < infile.eof() instead of !infile.eof() but it didn't work... this code at least worked so..

Comment: `while (!infile.eof())` is [bad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647/reading-from-text-file-until-eof-repeats-last-line) [practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Comment: @jrok that was what my book said... but okay

Comment: There are bad C++ books out there, unfortunately. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) for reccomendations.

Answer (score 2):

You might just read each line:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<deque>

int main()
{
    std::deque<std::string> names;
    std::ifstream infile("names.dat");
    std::string name;
    while(getline(infile, name))
        names.push_back(name);
    return 0;
}
```

Testing for EOF is often not a test for a successful input. Here the `getline` returns the stream and the condition `while(stream)` is testing the stream state.

Regarding the comment:

Have a `#include<algorithm>` and `std::sort(names.begin(), names.end());`

Comment: The OP wanted to read the data into an array, so this does not answer the question.

Comment: the reason why i wanted an array is that I have to eventually write a code that will sort the names alphabetically and thought an array will be easier

Comment: @weathergirl: you can sort an array with std::sort as well as some other containers.

Comment: @DieterLucking I tried your method and it gives me bunch of errors. I don't know what is wrong, since I haven't used deque ever yet.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a 2D dimensional array then as follows:

#### main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstring>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string first, last, myarray[200][2];

    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("names.dat");

    int i = 0;
    while (!infile.eof()) {
        infile >> first;
        myarray[i][0] = first;
        cout << myarray[i][0] << " ";

        if (infile.eof()) {
            cout << endl;
            break;
        }

        infile >> last;
        myarray[i][1] = last;
        cout << myarray[i][1] << " " << endl;
        ++i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

#### Output

```
Collins, Bill
Smith, Bart
Allen, Jim
```

That being said, I would personally use std::array or some more intelligent container type in C++, in general.

Comment: Quick question here, would mixing pre/post increment of i here make any difference??

Answer (score 1):

Just use one array of strings instead of two.

```
int main()
{
   string first, last, NAME[200];

   ifstream infile;
   infile.open("names.dat");
   int i = 0;

   while (true)
   {
      infile >> first;
      infile >> last;

      if (!infile.eof() && infile.good() )
      {
         NAME[i] = last + ", " + first;
         cout << NAME[i] << std::endl;
      }
      else
      {
         break;
      }
      ++i;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually, the OP's code is invalid, and I would not suggest to copy and paste that further on. Please also see the comments.