# C++ load from file keeps repeating last character

Tags: c++, do-while

So I am doing a compiler, and I have part of this LEXER which checks whether some chars form an INTEGER or a REAL number which is satisfied by this `EBNF //REAL: DIGIT {DIGIT} . DIGIT {DIGIT} [ (e|E) [(+ | -)] <DIGIT> {DIGIT}`

---

I have this part of the code (snippet of it) which checks that while it is not EOF or token is not match, it continues categorising the Tokens

```
while (!isEOF() && !tokenMatch)
            {

                //Checking for INTEGERS and REAL
                //INTEGERS: DIGIT {DIGIT}
                if (isDigit(ch))
                {
                    strBuffer += ch;

                    do
                    {
                        ch = nextChar();
                        strBuffer += ch;
                    }
                    while (isDigit(ch));

                    //REAL or ERROR
                    //REAL: DIGIT {DIGIT} . DIGIT {DIGIT} [ (e|E) [(+ | -)] <DIGIT> {DIGIT}

                    if (ch == '.')
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            ch = nextChar();
                            strBuffer += ch;
                        }
                        while (isDigit(ch));

                        //EXPONENT
                        if (ch == 'E' || ch == 'e')
                        {
                            char peek = input -> peek();
                            //CHECK FOR + | -

                            if(peek == '+' || peek == '-')
                            {
                                ch = nextChar();
                                strBuffer += ch;

                                ch = nextChar();
                                if (isDigit(ch))
                                {
                                    do
                                    {
                                        strBuffer +=ch;
                                        ch = nextChar();
                                        cout << strBuffer << endl;
                                    }
                                    while (isDigit(ch));
                                }
```

The problem lies when I have to load the text file and get the characters from it. IF for example a I write `123.12` **WITH** a Space, the Lexer will stop at the Whitespace. IF there are NO whitespace at EOF, the last do while loop keeps on repeating forever.

---

**Implementation of Next Char**
*input is an instream declared as:

```
ifstream* input  = new ifstream("test.txt");
```

---

```
char nextChar()
        {
            *input >> noskipws >> ch;

            //check for new line. If true, increment Row and start column from 1
            if(ch == '\n')
            {
                row ++;
                col = 1;
            }
            else if (ch == '\t')
            {
                col +=4;
            }
            else
            {
                col++;

            }

            return ch;
        }
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

thanks

Comment: Checking for `eof` is generally the wrong thing to do.  Try and read and if that fails then you're done.

Comment: Can you show the implementation of `nextChar`?

Comment: Still the same, it just keeps on repeating the last 2 of the decimal place

Comment: Why do you use `new` for `ifstream`?  Do you need to emulate Java or C#?

Comment: Your tab column calculation needs to use the '%' operator.

Comment: don't need to actually... but it works perfectly if I do a whitespace at the end

Comment: Where's the definition of `isDigit` and how does it differ from `std::isdigit`?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews it's a must that we do it as apparently we have to use it with JavaCC to do a Parse Tree or something. It's a requirement..nothing much I can do with that

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading from text file until EOF repeats last line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647/reading-from-text-file-until-eof-repeats-last-line)

Comment: @TomFenech Thanks for that link sir! Worked perfectly with the loop. I thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I would change `nextChar` to:

```
int nextChar()
{
   int ch = input->getc();

   if ( ch == EOF )
   {
      return ch;
   }
   //check for new line. If true, increment Row and start column from 1
   else if(ch == '\n')
   {
      row ++;
      col = 1;
   }
   else if (ch == '\t')
   {
      col +=4;
   }
   else
   {
      col++;
   }

   return ch;
}
```

and make sure that wherever `getChar` is called, use a variable of type `int` and compare the returned vale to `EOF` before proceeding.

Comment: What do you mean, compare the value of EOF with getChar()? Do I have to compare with -1 all the time?'

Comment: The tab processing is still wrong.  A tab is not equal to 4 spaces and does not move 4 columns.  A tab inserts zero or more spaces to the next tab column.  If you are on column 2 and the next tab column is 4, there will be 2 spaces added, not 4.

Comment: At the moment, columns are not being used, I'm more concerned about making the loop stop when it reaches EOF

Comment: @DodoSerebro, If you don't compare the returned value of `nextChar` with `EOF`, you will not know when the end of file has reached and you need to stop. My suggestion is to compare with the symbol `EOF` not `-1`.