# C++ attempting to read a char when EOF is reached

Tags: c++, char, eof

```
ifstream inputFile("blah.txt");
char c;
inputFile.read((char *)(&c), 1);
```

Let's say at the read, the file has already reached the `EOF`.
What value ends up in `c`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading from text file until EOF repeats last line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647/reading-from-text-file-until-eof-repeats-last-line)

Comment: &c is already a char*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Characters are extracted and stored until any of the following
>   conditions occurs:
>       ...
>       end of file condition occurs on the input sequence ...

Read more at: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read

So your `char` will contain the same value as before.