# Read multiple line in text file and write in another text file

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop, io, fstream

Here is my **scores.txt** file

```
7 2 11 4
9 1 30 3
5 3 20 3
10 1 10 2
5 0 50 0
```

This is a detais of 5 cricketer match inning

structure for above details:

In text file first column represent 7-overs, 2-maiden, 11-runs, 4-wickets.

I want to get five bowlers(count the column) in the text file and average(third column value divide by the fourth column) of that bowlers and print/display in the terminal.

like below:

```
Bowler    Average
1         2.75
2         10
3         6.66
4         5
5         NA
6         NA
```

above file has six bowlers but last one is repeated.I tried fix it to only five times because scores.txt file has five lines.

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
using std::setw;

int main(){
    float avg;
    int over,maiden,runs,wickets;
    ifstream scores;
    scores.open("scores.txt");
    if(!scores){
        cout<<"Error \n";
        return -1;
    }

    ofstream average("average.txt");
    if(!average){
        cout<<"Error \n";
        return -1;
    }

    average << "Bowler"<<"\t"<<"Average"<<endl;
    int i=1;
    //scores >> over >> maiden >> runs >> wickets;
    while(!scores.eof()){
        scores >> over >> maiden >> runs >> wickets;
        avg = runs/float(wickets);
        if(wickets == 0){
            average<<i<<"\t"<<"NA"<<endl;
        }else{
            //avg = runs/float(wickets);
            average << i<<"\t"<<avg<<endl;

        }
        i++;
    }
    scores.close();
    average.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading from text file until EOF repeats last line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647/reading-from-text-file-until-eof-repeats-last-line)

Comment: My problem is calculate average and write in text file as a 2 column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is this line

```
while(!scores.eof()){
```

When you have read the last line, `scores.eof()` is `false`, you try to read another line, the reading fail (and `scores.eof()` become `true`), you don't test if the reading is with or without error and you use two times the values of the last line.

I suggest something like

```
while( scores >> over >> maiden >> runs >> wickets ){
    avg = runs/float(wickets);
```