# Creating a hashtable using vectors of vectors?

Tags: c++, vector, hashtable

I'm currently trying to write a program that creates a hash table, using vectors of vectors for my collision resolution method.

The problem I am facing is that during runtime, a vector of vectors is created, but all of the Entry vectors inside remain of size 0. I know my put functions are faulty but I don't know where/why.

This is my first time creating a hash table and I'd appreciate any assistance in what the problem might be. My goal is to create a vector of Entry vectors, and each Entry has its associated key and value. After finding the hash value for a new Entry key, it should check the Entry vectors' key values to see if the key already exists. If it does, it updates that key's value.

This is a segment of table.cpp:

```
Table::Table(unsigned int maximumEntries) : maxEntries(100){
    this->maxEntries = maximumEntries;
    this->Tsize = 2*maxEntries;

}

Table::Table(unsigned int entries, std::istream& input){ //do not input more than the specified number of entries.

    this->maxEntries = entries;
    this->Tsize = 2*maxEntries;

    std::string line = "";

    int numEntries = 0;


    getline(input, line);
    while(numEntries<maxEntries || input.eof()){ // reads to entries or end of file
        int key;
        std::string strData = "";

        convertToValues(key, strData, line);

        put(key, strData); // adds each of the values to the tab;e

        numEntries++;

        getline(input,line);

    }

}



void Table::put(unsigned int key, std::string data){ 
    Entry newEntryObj(key,data); //create a new Entry obj
    put(newEntryObj);
}


void Table::put(Entry e){ // creating the hash table

    assert(currNumEntries < maxEntries);

    int hash = (e.get_key() % Tsize);

    Entry newEntry = Entry(e.get_key(), e.get_data()); 

    for(int i = 0; i < hashtable[hash].size(); i++){
        if (e.get_key() == hashtable[hash][i].get_key()){ 
            hashtable[hash][i].set_data(e.get_data());
        }
        else{
            hashtable[hash].push_back(newEntry);  // IF KEY DOESNT EXIST, ADD TO THE VECTOR
        }
    }
}
```

This is Table.h

```
#ifndef table_h
#define table_h

#include "entry.h"
#include <string>
#include <istream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


class Table{

  public: 

    Table(unsigned int max_entries = 100); //Builds empty table with maxEntry value
    Table(unsigned int entries, std::istream& input); //Builds table designed to hold number of entires


    void put(unsigned int key, std::string data); //creates a new Entry to put in
    void put(Entry e);  //puts COPY of entry into the table
    std::string get(unsigned int key) const; //returns string associated w/ param, "" if no entry exists
    bool remove(unsigned int key); //removes Entry containing the given key

    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const Table& t); //overloads << operator to PRINT the table.

    int getSize();

    std::vector<std::vector<Entry>> getHashtable(); 


  private:
    std::vector<std::vector<Entry>> hashtable; //vector of vectors
    int Tsize; //size of table equal to twice the max number of entries
    int maxEntries;
    int currNumEntries;

#endif /* table_h */
};
```

and Entry.h:

```
#include <string>
#include <iosfwd>

class Entry {

public:
    // constructor
    Entry(unsigned int key = 0, std::string data = "");

    // access and mutator functions
    unsigned int get_key() const;
    std::string get_data() const;
    static unsigned int access_count();
    void set_key(unsigned int k);
    void set_data(std::string d);

    // operator conversion function simplifies comparisons
    operator unsigned int () const;

    // input and output friends
    friend std::istream& operator>>
    (std::istream& inp, Entry &e);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<
    (std::ostream& out, Entry &e);

private:
    unsigned int key;
    std::string data;
    static unsigned int accesses;

};
```

Comment: Just a side question: Why not use `std::unordered_map`?

Comment: I'm not allowed to use  <map>, <set>, <unordered_map> and <unordered_set>. We're learning how to create hash tables from scratch :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various problems with your code, but the answer for your question would be this:

In

```
void Table::put(Entry e){ // creating the hash table
```

Have a look at the loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < hashtable[hash].size(); i++){
```

Now, `hashtable[hash]` is a vector. But initially it doesn't have any elements. So `hashtable[hash].size()` is 0. So you don't enter the loop.

On top of this, trying to access `hashtable[hash]` in the first place results in undefined behaviour due to `hashtable` not being properly resized to `Tsize`. Try this in your constructor(s):

```
this->maxEntries = maximumEntries;
this->Tsize = 2*maxEntries;
this->hashtable.resize(this->Tsize);
```

EDIT:

It would be easier for you to understand if you use `std::vector::at` function instead of `std::vector::operator[]`. For example:

```
void Table::put(Entry e){ // creating the hash table

    assert(currNumEntries < maxEntries);

    int hash = (e.get_key() % Tsize);

    Entry newEntry = Entry(e.get_key(), e.get_data()); 

    for(int i = 0; i < hashtabl.at(hash).size(); i++){
        if (e.get_key() == hashtable.at(hash).at(i).get_key()){ 
            hashtable.at(hash).at(i).set_data(e.get_data());
        }
        else{
            hashtable.at(hash).push_back(newEntry);  // IF KEY DOESNT EXIST, ADD TO THE VECTOR
        }
    }
}
```

Without resizing `hashtable`, this code would throw an `out_of_range` exception when you try to do `hashtable.at(hash)` the first time.

P.S. None of this is tested.

Comment: Thank you so much! The other problem I seem to be having is that I'm running into an infinite loop, it adds all of my data from my text file and then infinitely adds more empty data. Why might that be?

Comment: Actually I figured it out. If i change my while loop to while(!input.oef()) it finishes accordingly.

Comment: @C.Lee: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647/reading-from-text-file-until-eof-repeats-last-line